# Word 2011: Keyboard shortcuts for accepting/rejecting a tracked change AND moving to the next change

Tags: keyboard, ms-office

Is there such a built-in shortcut for doing such action pairs? (e.g. accept+move to next, using a single shortcut)

If not, how can I define such a custom shortcut?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is actually quite easy to do, once you know where to look. (Unfortunately for me I didn't know about this until my thesis was done. ***Not that I'm bitter or anything.***)

1) In MSWord, go to the Tools Menu and then choose "Customize Keyboard"

[image]

2) Under "Categories" choose "All Commands" and then look for "AcceptChangesAndAdvance". Select it, then click in the box next to "Press new keyboard shortcut" as shown here:

[image]

3) Enter an unused keyboard combination (I chose ⌘ + ⌥ + Y for "Yes I want this change"). Note that the "Assign" button is now activated. Use it. Then click "OK".

[image]

That should be all you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

There are good help pages direct in the application or online.

[Word keyboard shortcuts](http://mac2.microsoft.com/help/office/14/en-us/word/item/f7701a9f-35bc-49c5-a5b5-8c24b085a166?category=0fd37350-97cb-4c7b-bc4d-1725e279a4cd)

There are some for reviewing documents, but not for what you search.

But you should create your own: [Create or delete a keyboard shortcut](http://mac2.microsoft.com/help/office/14/en-us/word/item/37dfe7e2-8158-45c1-8556-ec1cbd343f4d?category=0fd37350-97cb-4c7b-bc4d-1725e279a4cd)

Comment: I'm asking specifically about accepting tracked changes - those don't seem to be trivial to set up

Answer (score 0):

1. Save the document as Word 98/2000 .doc format
2. Open in Word 98
3. Tools/track changes/accept or reject changes
4. Find next
5. Either click accept or reject, which will do so and automatically find next, or "find next" which will leave the tracked change and find next

Answer (score 0):

In office 2007 you can set a custom shortkey at "File -> Options -> Customize Ribbon"

There set a nice key, like ctrl-shift-Arrow :)

Comment: The OP says it's Office 2011.  Office to 2011 is for PC so, how is this answer relevant?